# How to build development infrastructure for Spring Boot and Node.js?

Tags: java, reactjs, devops

My friend and I want to make a collaborative project for studying purposes in React and Spring Boot respectively.

I am a junior Java developer and he is at entry level in front-end.

What we want to do is make a very simple application in which I will expose some endpoints and he will call them.

But we want to build a more "professional" infrastructure.

We do not know much about DevOps staff, we want to have a desktop pc as the deployment server and each of us to work on our laptops.

We do not know if one should have the environment the other uses. Will I be needing to install Node on my laptop? Will he be needing to have a Tomcat server? How will we have to setup our environments so that we will be able to collaborate?

We need guidance, please help or provide some resources on the matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, both should be able to checkout the sources from the VCS, run an automated build procedure (using gradle, for example), and run everything on your own machine. Automating everything might be difficult at the beginning if you have no experience with build tools, but being able to run everything on your machine is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to use SpringBoot then you don't need to install a Tomcat server. SpringBoot uses embedded Tomcat.

Briefly, you can have an infrastructure like this:

On your deployment server install node+npm, JDK, GIT server and Jenkins. If your desktop is powerful, then you can try to install node+npm and JDK in one VM and GIT server and Jenkins in another one. For virtualization, you can use VirtualBox. To create the VM's, you can use Vagrant and Ansible for provisioning.

On your laptop, install JDK, Maven, GIT client, IntelliJ (recommended) or Eclipse

On your colleague's laptop, install node + npm, GIT client

You can find [here](https://github.com/tavyy/reactive-jersey) an example of SpringBoot with Jersey, to expose simple REST endpoints.